# Order of an element in an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Suppose that (*R*, + , •), is an integral domain, where + and • are the usual operations, addition and multiplication respectively, and the non zero element *r*, as considered as an element of the abelian group (*R*, +), has finite order *k*. Prove that *k* is prime.

So at this point I have myself quite confused on what seems like a very easy question. From my understanding I want to add *r* to itself until I reach the additive identity, 0. The question tells us *r* should be added *k* times. So,

(*r + r + r + ... + r*) *k* times = *kr* = 0.

However, since *R* is an integral domain *kr* cannot be equal to 0. This is where my problem is.

My first thought was my definition of order is incorrect, and I will need to multiply *r*, *k* times before it will equal the multiplicative identity. If this is the case I am still unsure how to proceed...

Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: You mean that $kr$ cannot be zero unless either $k$ or $r$ is. So you conclude that about $k$?

Comment: Ok, so we know *r* is not zero, therefore *k* must be zero. But isn't that rather trivial, that a number added to itself 0 times would be zero. This would also imply that *r* has order 0..?

Comment: @SenoritaChad Note that $k$ is an integer, not an element of $R$. So you cannot apply the domain property. What you can say is that $k1=0$, where  $1$ is the identity in $R$.

Comment: @egreg Ah of course... That was awfully silly of me assume that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the concept of the characteristic of a domain.

Note if $(r+r+\cdots+ r) = 0$, then $r(1+1+\cdots+1) = 0$. So since $r \neq 0$, $1+\cdots + 1 = 0$ as your ring is a domain. The characteristic of a ring is the order of $1$ in the additive group of the ring.

Now suppose that $1+1+\cdots + 1 = 0$ where the sum has $n$ terms. Then if $n$ is composite, say $n = pq$ so that $p,q<n$, we must have $(1+1+\cdots+1)(1+1+\cdots + 1) = 0$ where the former sum has $p$ terms and the latter $q$. In fact, we may call those terms $p$ and $q$ itself, but then we have $pq = 0$ in $R$, a domain. So one of $p$ or $q$ must be $0$. But by definition of order in a group, it must be minimal, and so we've contradicted our claim of $n$ as the order of $1$. So $n$ must be prime.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks. However, I realize the problems states that *r* indeed has finite order, and therefore eliminating the possibility that *k* is composite confirms that it must be prime. I'm now struggling to see how even if *k* is prime, how does that assure us that *r* really does have a finite order?

Comment: That's sort of by definition -- if $r + r + \cdots + r = 0$ where the sum has a prime number (say, $k$) of terms, then $r$ has order $k<\infty$.

Comment: Alright, that's fair enough. Thanks for the help. The question/answer is crystal clear after your explanation! Thanks a bunch.